# Preallocating the space in Matlab without knowing the size?

Tags: matlab

I am constructing a vector `X` in Matlab by concatenating the outcomes of each iteration in a loop procedure.

What I am doing at the moment is

```
X=[];
for j=1:N
    %do something that delivers a vector A
    %X=[X;A]
end
```

It is not possible to predict a priori the size of A. Is there any way in which I can preallocate the space?

Comment: In case it's a "Yes / No Question", the answer is **No**. You may preallocate an approximation of the space, or space that should be large enough (supposed you have some knowledge of A)... but not "the space".

Comment: If you really can't get any information on the size of X from `j` and `N`, then the best you can do is over-allocate, hope you don't have to expand it, then trim vector after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
A=cell(1,N); %Pre-allocating A instead of X as a cell array
for k=1:N    %I changed the name of loop variable since `j` is reserved for imag numbers
  %Here I am generating a matrix of 5 columns and random number of rows. 
  %I kept number of columns to be constant (5) because you used X=[X;A] 
  %in the question which means number of columns will always be same
  A{k} =  rand(randi([1,10],1,1),5); %doing something that delivers a vector A   
end
X = vertcat(A{:});
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you think I can gain significant speed for large dimensions?

Comment: @user3285148 Yes it will be significantly faster than the code in the question.  btw how large dimensions are you dealing with?

Comment: Size(X,1) can be 200,000

Comment: @user3285148 I tested both the codes for `N= 200,000`. For my system, my code took almost 0.6 seconds while your code is taking forever. No idea for how more long it will keep running

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated