# Merge matrixes that are generated by function

Tags: matlab, matrix, merge, bind

I can't figure out how to merge (vertically) some matrices, where all have 2 columns, but a different number of rows.  I have created a function that returns those matrices.

For example, when I call it for `x = 1` and given parameters `C` and `CE` I get:

```
>> myFunction2(1,C,CE)

ans =

    1.0000    0.1704
    2.0000    0.6381
    3.0000    0.1704
```

for `x = 2`

```
>> myFunction2(2,C,CE)

ans =

    14.0000   -0.4472
    25.0000   -0.4472
     6.0000   -0.4472
```

etc. How can I merge them, in order to get a single matrix

```
ans =

    1.0000    0.1704
    2.0000    0.6381
    3.0000    0.1704
   14.0000   -0.4472
   25.0000   -0.4472
    6.0000   -0.4472
```

I have to call `myFunction` 255 times (it is equal to the length of a list I am using). Unfortunately, I cannot provide with reproducible code since there are lots of input files that are loaded in MATLAB generating those numbers.

Comment: you can use the function `vertcat` or use `matcat = [mat1;mat2]`

Comment: btw, if you'd be getting different number of rows each time but number of columns remain same, refer to this question → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909753/preallocating-the-space-in-matlab-without-knowing-the-size

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks for your input. I follow the method suggested, and although it creates me requested matrix, all values are devided by 1000. output is in the form of: `final =

   1.0e+03 *

    0.0010    0.0002
    0.0020    0.0006
    0.0030    0.0002
    0.0950    0.0001` . any idea how to get it as orifinally calculated by my function? (formai does not work in comment, after `1.0e+03 *` I get the two columns, but instead of 1 I get 0.0010, instead of 0.1704 I get 0.0002 etc

Comment: The values are not divided by 1000, but 1.0e+03 is taken as a common! Usually this happens when some of the values in your data are much larger than the others. `format` *should* work here. Read [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#btixwz8-1_2) from the documentaiton